# Link not clickable

Tags: html, css

Project link:

```
http://50.87.144.37/~projtest/team/design/AHG/brochure/#28
```

The dark grey stripe at the bottom is an anchor tag, I can't seem to figure as to why it is not clickable. The css is very simple. The parent class is `posRel` and the anchor tag is `efgLink3` and 'bg-img' is the image over which a tag is arriving.

Html:

```
<div class="container posRel">
                                <a class="efgLink3" target="_blank" href="http://www.efginternational.com/"></a>

                <img class="bg-img" src="pages/preview/cover-back.jpg" style="height: 587px; width: 415px;">
                <img class="bg-img zoom-large" src="pages/preview/cover-zoomed-back.jpg" style="height: 587px; width: 415px;">
            </div>
```

Css:

```
.posRel{
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
 }

.efgLink3 {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #333;
    display: block;
    height: 70px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 79%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 11;
}

.bg-img {
    left: 0;
    margin-top: 10px;
    max-width: 100% !important;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Comment: If that site goes dead this question is useless. Please add the relevant html that reproduces your issue in the question.

Comment: can you provide us fiddle..?

Comment: can u post a jsfiddle please

Comment: i can able to click that.

Comment: Possibly the most un user-friendly site i've seen in a while.

Comment: I can click it after zooming it by double click

Comment: @NickR, it is not a website, this is an e-brochure. And clicking after zooming is possible, yes, but it should be clickable before zooming as well.

Comment: Off-topic, but trying to navigate it is a horrible user experience for me, it's all tiny images. Meaning you have to zoom in to read it, you can't select any text.

Comment: I really don't care what the user experience is, I just need to satisfy the client requirements, is that a difficult concept for you to understand? And I know you stated it, but still, stay on topic.

Comment: Found the issue,     'pointer-events' was set to none.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue, 'pointer-events' was set to none, thanks to all for looking up.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in your HTML:

```
<a href="http://www.efginternational.com/" target="_blank" class="efgLink3"/>
```

Your anchor is empty, so there's nothing to click on.

```
<img src="pages/preview/cover-back.jpg" class="bg-img"/>
<img src="pages/preview/cover-zoomed-back.jpg" class="bg-img zoom-large"/>
```

Presumably one or both of these belongs inside the anchor.

Comment: Empty? If you go to the 27th page, you will see that the "EFG" logo in the left page is linked in just similar way. It is working all over the layout, except the last page.

Comment: With a self-closing `<a>` tag?

Comment: No. It is just the same, here:                     <a href="http://www.efginternational.com/" target="_blank" class="efgLink2"></a>

Comment: Those are logically equivalent. Presumably you have some code that's supposed to add a child to the anchor at runtime, but it's not doing so.

Comment: Found the issue,     'pointer-events' was set to none, thanks for looking up.